# Sql Server Email servers

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

How can one optimize the database structure that currently has two tables "tbl_incoming" and "tbl_outgoing" .The data the tables are going to hold is pretty much obvious .tbl_incoming is saving all the incoming messages to a server while the server's replies are stored in the tbl_outgoing for a particular incoming message .
Lets say that I found myself handling a large amount of data for both tables. A 1 to many relationship from tbl_incoming to tbl_outgoing .
What is the best way to do the optimization if i have a million+ incoming messages and for each message tons of outgoing message and i want to retrieve them all .

[image]

Comment: I have already created the index for incoming_message_id in outgoing_messages.What more can be done ?

Comment: Can you share your data structure?

Comment: @pcraft Sorry - that site is blocked here.

Comment: Are you actually having performance problem or you're just optimizing prematurely? How does one incoming generate "tons" of outgoing.

Comment: @jfrobishow its a simple one to many relationship ....for one incoming message there are tons of server replies and yes i am just optimizing prematurely.

Comment: @pcraft try it with an index, if it perform badly then you should look for solution.  Until you've tried with real-world data you won't know.

Comment: @jfrobishow thanks I will wait for the real data :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting comment to answer -

Try it with an index, if it perform badly then you should look for solution. Until you've tried with real-world data you won't know